What is the maximum heap size for file generation?
I am about to release a WASM app which needs to generate a huge file on the client device to function and store it there to avoid regeneration.
We are talking about a 1-2GB. It is guaranteed to be below the 4GB threshold (32 bits limit).
What are the file limits on desktop, mobile? Is that even possible ?
Update:
Seems like 4GB is the limit for now

so you have this feature but never check if this is possible before ?!?

What kind of huge file is it? Why does it need to be so big? How are you generating it? Sounds like an X-Y problem to me.

@Stargateur: it is a bonus I though about afterwards: if it cannot be made, I will stream little blocks as needed but it is less desirable. Not a showstopper by any means.

@Enigmativity: a lookup table

@LeXav - I asked three questions. Is "a lookup table" the answer to all three?

@LeXav - If you are "generating" a lookup table then you must have a generating function. Why not just use that function?

@Enigmativity: yes lookup table generated on the server because it is kind of slow to generate on a mobile (15 min at 100%.. well people will kill me as their battery won't keep up)

Ok I have my answer. Please look at the edit.

As my update in my post suggests, 4GB.

It depends on various factors such as system resources, OS, Version and we can change and increase memory up to 2GB.

Yes, you are right it depends on the hardware. Up to 2GB to total 4GB, right ?
